# How to check if update mysql table is successful?

Tags: mysql, node.js

api.js:

```
function verifyEmailAddressCode(emailAddress,userCode,callback){
    var updateSQL = "UPDATE emailverification SET verified = 1 WHERE email_address = '" + emailAddress + "' AND verificationCode = '" + userCode + "'" ;
    db(function(err,conn){
        conn.query(updateSQL,function(err,results){
            if(err){
                conn.release();
                return callback(err,null);
            }
            conn.release();
            return callback(null, results);
        });
    });
}
```

results return:

```
OkPacket {fieldCount: 0, affectedRows: 0, insertId: 0, serverStatus: 34, warningCount: 0, …}
```

Results show that `affectedRows: 0` which means update is not successful. How can I access the variable `affectedRows`?

Comment: `results.affectedRows`

Comment: 0 rows doesn't mean that there was an error, it means that no rows matched the `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: It can also mean that `verified` was already `1` in those rows, so they didn't need to be updated.